# xmonad: control timing between sequential keybindings

Tags: xmonad

Is there a way to do this?

I mean, suppose I have a keybinding such as `<Super> f f`. Then to make it work I have to type the keys (`<Super> f f`), but not too fast.

It seems if I type `<Super> f` xmonad will wait a long time for more input. I like this behavior.

However, if I type too fast, it doesn't work. It seems to me the issue isn't how fast I type, but if, in the middle of typing very fast, I press two keys simultaneously.

Is there a way to get around this? If not, is it implementable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the binding expects the keys to be applied in sequence (and not combined), it's possible for the key events to arrive in the wrong order and be misinterpreted by the application.  X events are not guaranteed to arrive in the given order (it just **usually** works).

Timing in a sequence would be up to the application (whether to treat them as "the same" time or not).  Similarly, in various applications the timing for double- and triple-clicking is — up to the **application** to decide if the clicks are close enough to treat as one composite event.

Comment: I was thinking something along the lines of having two bindings, one for (say) "Super-a" and one for "Super a", to cover both cases. I tried doing this specifically and it did not work.

Comment: What I was trying to do was emulate Spacemacs. And in Spacemacs, I can press "SPC w l" super fast, and it will work.